# Display title for view in back button but not in navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, ios5, uinavigationbar

I would like to set the title of my view to "Main Menu", however, I do not want the title to appear in the navigation toolbar.  The reason I want to set the title is so the back button has the title "Main Menu".  Is there a way to do this?  Here is the relevant code:

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        self.title = @"Main Menu";
        // Custom initialization

    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the title of back button item, you should write in viewDidLoad method as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Main Menu"
 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
    [backButtonItem release];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much hoshi, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Set the title right before you push the next view controller:

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Main Menu"];
[navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
```

and set it to a blank string (or `nil`) in `viewWillAppear`:

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the back button for this one. You need to set the value of the back button in the `Main Menu` controller before it pushes the next `UIViewController`.

For an explanation of why check out my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250904/back-button-text-does-not-change/8250963#8250963) and the docs for [View controller programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1)